# Javascript callback not firing when using this

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, callback

Hello I have this code which works fine

```
var app = {

    callback: null,
    jqmReady: null,
    pgReady: null,

    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function(callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
        this.jqmReady = $.Deferred();
        this.pgReady = $.Deferred();
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', app.pgReady.resolve, false);
        $(document).on("pageinit", app.jqmReady.resolve);
        $.when(app.jqmReady, app.pgReady).then(app.isReady);
    },

    isReady: function() {
        app.callback();
    }

};
```

code is being initialized like this:

```
    app.initialize(function(){
        navigator.notification.alert('Hello there!', function(){}, 'Notify', 'Ok');
    });
```

however my isReady function was like this at first and the callback was not called:

```
    isReady: function() {
        this.callback();
    }
```

Why is this happening ? isn't the scope of `this = app` inside `isReady()` like in the `initialize()` function ?
Could someone explain to me why it doesn't work with `this.callback()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created an object, not a class or an instance of a class.    Change your `this` to `app` throughout your initialize function.  You're doing that already in your `isReady` and `bindEvents` functions.  So keep that going in `initialize`.

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification, I was a little confused because I'm used at creating classes and instances as you mentioned